# Utilizar uma variável para limitar a leitura de caracteres com o fscanf e máscara de dados

Tags: c

Criei uma estrutura que guarda três registros quaisquer. Esses registros eu leio de um arquivo f. Eles possuem um tamanho definido, no caso abaixo o primeiro dado tem três caracteres, o segundo 17 e o terceiro três. Utilizei assim pois os dados podem vir de qualquer forma, mas o padrão é garantido. Exemplo dentro do arquivo f:

999 Eduardo Oliveira SI

111EduardoOliveira SI (Dois espaços antes de SI, não consegui colocar aqui)

```
for (i = 0; i < qtde_registros; i++)
{
    fscanf(f,"%3s",rt[i].m);
    rt[i].m[3]='\0';
    fscanf(f,"%17c",rt[i].n);
    rt[i].n[17]='\0';
    fscanf(f,"%3c",rt[i].c);
    rt[i].c[3]='\0';
}
```

Está funcionando perfeitamente, o problema é que não quero deixar esse tamanho fixo, quero pegar o tamanho de cada um dos três dados com o usuário ou por outro arquivo. Como posso substituir esses número "3,17,3" por variáveis. Exemplo do que quero:

```
int tamPrimeiroDado=3;
int tamSegundoDado=17;
int tamTerceiroDado=3;

for (i = 0; i < qtde_registros; i++)
{
    fscanf(f,"% >>AQUI(tamPrimeiroDado)<< s",rt[i].m);
    rt[i].m[tamPrimeiroDado]='\0';
    fscanf(f,"% >>AQUI(tamSegundoDado)<< c",rt[i].n);
    rt[i].n[tamSegundoDado]='\0';
    fscanf(f,"% >>AQUI(tamTerceiroDado)<< c",rt[i].c);
    rt[i].c[tamTerceiroDado]='\0';
}
```

Com um ou mais 'for', 'fseek', 'fgetc' ... consigo o que quero, mas há alguma forma de fazer isso com as máscaras de dados em C? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scanf, sscanf e fscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) não suportam diretamente a especificação de tamanho variável de campo.

É possível no entanto usar truques, como mostrado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410690/scanf-variable-length-specifier).

A melhor solução no entanto é usar [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) e [calloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc), e fazer a separação dos campos manualmente.
Estas funções (scanf, fscanf, sscanf) são muito frágeis, na prática não são usadas "na vida real".

```
#include <stdio.h>  // fgets, printf
#include <stdlib.h> // calloc
#include <string.h> // memcpy

int main()
{
  // definicao dos tamanhos dos campos
  int tamCpo1 = 3;
  int tamCpo2 = 17;
  int tamCpo3 = 3;

  // definicao do tamanho do registro
  int tamRegistro = tamCpo1 + tamCpo2 + tamCpo3;

  // aloca memoria para os campos individuais
  // soma 1 para zero binario no final
  char* cpo1 = calloc(tamCpo1+1, 1);
  char* cpo2 = calloc(tamCpo2+1, 1);
  char* cpo3 = calloc(tamCpo3+1, 1);

  // aloca memoria para o registro
  // soma 2 para reservar espaco para \n\0
  char* registro = calloc(tamRegistro+2, 1);

  // para computar tamanho do registro lido
  int tamRegLido;

  // arquivo a ser lido
  FILE* arq;

  // abre arquivo arq
  arq = fopen("teste.txt", "r");
  if (!arq)
  {
    printf("*\n");
    printf("* arquivo 'teste.txt' inexistente\n");
    printf("*\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("*\n");

  // loop de leitura dos registros
  for (;;)
  {
    // tenta ler um registro
    if (!fgets(registro, tamRegistro+2, arq))
    {
      printf("*\n");
      if (feof(arq))
        printf("* fim de arquivo\n");
      else
        printf("* erro na leitura\n");
      break; // sai do while
    }

    // ok, leu um registro

    // computa o tamanho do registro lido
    tamRegLido = strlen(registro);

    if (tamRegLido < tamRegistro + 1)
    {
      printf("* ignorando registro com tamanho menor\n");
      continue; // volta para inicio do while
    }

    if (registro[tamRegistro] != '\n')
    {
      printf("* ignorando registro com tamanho maior\n");
      continue; // volta para inicio do while
    }

    // registro lido com tamanho correto

    // separa os campos
    memcpy(cpo1, registro, tamCpo1);
    memcpy(cpo2, registro+tamCpo1, tamCpo2);
    memcpy(cpo3, registro+tamCpo1+tamCpo2, tamCpo3);

    // mostra os campos1 lidos
    printf("* campo 1: [%s]\n", cpo1);
    printf("* campo 2: [%s]\n", cpo2);
    printf("* campo 3: [%s]\n", cpo3);
    printf("*\n");
  }

  printf("*\n");
  printf("* fim\n");
  printf("*\n");
}
```